# How to process huge memory consumption task on Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that is bond to a storage queue. I am processing a message of more than 2GB memory to end the task. But Azure Function only allow 1.5GB per instance to process the task.

How i can increase the memory allowed limit in Azure Function?

OR

Is there any other way, so that I can manage these type of task?

Comment: have you checked web jobs ?

Comment: I have seen this but i didn't find how to bind it with storage queue.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to. HTH.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am looking into by following the shared link.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions can also run in dedicated plans (App Service Plans) which would give you the ability to pick much larger workers to meet your workload requirements.

You'd be giving up the features you have with the consumption/dynamic plan, and billing would be based on the worker size you select, but the programming model and runtime features are the same.